# From where author, create date,title is coming in Excel after using PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

This is my code

```
<?php   
        if($_POST['submited'])
        {
         if($_POST['dwnld_query']=="All applicants")
         {
           $q="select * from es_enquiry";
           $result=mysql_query($q);
         }
        header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
    header( "Content-disposition: attachment; filename='".$_POST['dwnld_query']."'.xls" );

    // print your data here. note the following:
    // - cells/columns are separated by tabs ("\t")
    // - rows are separated by newlines ("\n")
            echo 'RegNo'."\t".'App for class'."\t".'FirstName'."\t".'Middle-Name'."\t".'Last-Name'."\t".'Gender'."\t".'Father Name'."\t".'DOB'."\t".'AGE'."\t".'Child Category'."\t".'Parent Category'."\t".'TC Case'."\t".'Last School Name'."\t".'TC Date'."\t".  'TC No'."\t".'CGPA'."\n";
            $tc_case;
                $tc_date;
                $tc_no;
              while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result))
              {
                if($row->last_school_type=="KV"){$tc_case="Yes";}
                else{$tc_case="No";}
                if($row->kv_tc_date==" ")
                {                 
                         $tc_date="-";

                }
                else
                {
                  $tc_date=$row->kv_tc_date;
                }
                if($row->kv_tc_no==" ")
                {
                   $tc_no="-";
                }
                else
                {
                  $tc_no=$row->kv_tc_date;
                }

          // for example:
          echo  $row->eq_application_no."\t".$row->eq_class."\t".$row->eq_name."\t".$row->mid_name."\t".$row->last_name."\t".$row->eq_sex."\t".$row->father_name."\t".$row->eq_dob."\t".$row->age."\t".$row->scat_id."\t".$row->parent_cate_id."\t".$tc_case ."\t".$row->eq_prv_acdmic."\t".$tc_date."\t".$tc_no."\t".$row->last_class_cgpa."\n";
          }
     }
?>
```

When I download the excel file it shows the Author:Maarten Balliauw, Subject:Office 2007 XLSX Test Document, Title:Office 2007 XLSX Test Document, Categories:Test result file, Tags:office 2007 openxml php. AS you all can see in my code nothing is mentioned about these then from where these are coming and how to change or remove these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using PHPExcel, these properties are set against the PHPExcel object itself, in the `Document Properties`, e.g.

```
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()
    ->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
    ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
    ->setTitle("PHPExcel Test Document")
    ->setSubject("PHPExcel Test Document")
    ->setDescription("Test document for PHPExcel, generated using PHP classes.")
    ->setKeywords("office PHPExcel php")
    ->setCategory("Test result file");
```

But your code isn't using PHPExcel at all; and doesn't even look as though it's creating an Excel file, but simply creating a tab-separated value file by hand (and without even using safer PHP's simpler and safer built-in fputcsv() function)... so it certainly isn't generating a file that is even capable of containing any document properties.

So check what script is really generating what file

Comment: OK I got your point but what about this code where not a single property is set on Excel document.

`require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
Your code ....
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Enquiry_Format.'.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');`

Comment: I used your code in the code I mentioned in my second comment but properties are not coming og Excel Document, what is your opinion on this.

Comment: My opinion is that you've done something wrong if you can't see those properties in your Excel workbook.... what properties are shown for the .xlsx file that you're generating, because there are default values for some properties if you don't set them manually? If you run the scripts in /Examples, do they show the properties correctly?